# Why NSLookup is giving different result than Ping?

Tags: windows, dns, ip, ping, nslookup

Let me confess, stupid question. but its not a duplicate question.

1. I was trying to see what is IP address of some server (its a local server, within LAN).
2. when I simply did, 'Ping someServer' I got back ipv6 address(which i hate).
3. so I try 'nslookup someServer' in hope that I will get ipv4 address, which I got (10.255.4.10)
4. then I read somewhere and tried 'Ping someServer -4' to get the ipv4 address, I got the Ip but this is different than what I got from point 3 above(10.255.4.236)

I have checked my host file, it has nothing against someServer, so my question is why am I getting different results?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

nslookup is a look up of records in DNS servers. The response from this was what the someServer operator has published as their first point of call - this server could well redirect requests through to other computers in the network depending on load or task required

ping will give you the ip of the computers that you actually interacted with

Maybe 10.255.4.10 redirected your request to 10.255.4.236?

Answer (score 0):

A hostname can (and usually does) return more than one IP address. Both nslookup and ping only use the first entry returned. Additionally, the name server will specify a Time to Live (TTL) for the record, so after the time has expired the IP addresses could change or be reordered. If you use DiG or host (if you have them) it will give you more information.

For example:

```
$ dig superuser.com
;; ANSWER SECTION:
superuser.com.          300     IN      A       151.101.129.69
superuser.com.          300     IN      A       151.101.1.69
superuser.com.          300     IN      A       151.101.193.69
superuser.com.          300     IN      A       151.101.65.69
```

The TTL is 300 seconds and there are four IP addresses. They are "A" (address) records (IP6 are "AAAA").

Or, with host:

```
$ host superuser.com
superuser.com has address 151.101.129.69
superuser.com has address 151.101.193.69
superuser.com has address 151.101.65.69
superuser.com has address 151.101.1.69
```

Notice the order changed.